# Is is faster in php to run a boolean check or just a simple == 1 / == 0

Tags: php, boolean

Is it faster in php to check for a boolean value like,

```
 if($var)
```

or

```
 if($var == 1)
```

and

```
 if(!$var)
```

or

```
 if($var == 1)
```

`var` can only be 1 or 0.

Comment: <quote>Premature optimization is the root of all evil</quote>

Comment: it is not premature for one, two I don't need to worry about readability the only factor I need to worry about is speed.

Comment: Write a test script that loops over a randomized value a few million times with each of the possible scenarios and see. I suspect the optimizer in APC or eAccelerator will optimize that away for you and if your not using one of those - they'll increase your speed more than the way you write your if/then/else.

Comment: The primary focus here should be on readability not speed.  So the name of the $var is critical.  If you have something like if(!$looping) thats more clear than if($looping != 1).  However in another case you might want to say if($POST('submit')){ do something} .  It all depends on the context and there are no hard and fast rules in programming.

Answer (score 1):

I expected that directly assessing the truthy-ness of a variable would be quicker than testing if two variables are equal. My tests show this to be the case. You would expect there to be a higher level of indirection when the == operator is evaluated (it's a call to an additional function which returns a truth value?), and hence it adds some very tiny overhead.

Some people have suggested this is a premature micro-optimisation. I personally don't think it is because

1. Personally I prefer to read `if ($var) {}`  than `if ($var == 1) {}`
2. It only takes a very basic understanding of the language to know that any truthy (equivalent to true) value can be evaluated inside the if statement
3. In some ways it might raise awareness of how the if statement works (anything that discourages `if ($var == true) {}` if only by a fraction is surely helpful)

Given that it is faster as well, it would seem that these points, albeit marginal, indicate `if ($var) {}` as the better option. At least that's how it seems to me when factoring in my personal preferences.

Answer (score 0):

if($var) is faster. You can check this link out http://hbfs.wordpress.com/2008/08/26/optimizing-boolean-expressions-for-speed/ for more detail explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Check this site out:

http://www.phpbench.com/